# AngularJS view knows about the controller by ng-controller directive

Tags: angularjs

I was reading about the basics of angular js from the a video http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-in-60-ish-minutes-the-ebook, [at 00:23:47 point](https://youtu.be/i9MHigUZKEM?t=23m47s), author said that View does not know about Controller, and Controller does not know about the View.

But in my opinion, View knows about the Controller via:
1. We have ng-controller directive in the view, which knows the name of the controller
2. We have various models which are resolving through the controller's scope variable.

How angular's statement is valid 'View does not know about the controller'??

Comment: You misheard what the author said - "The view **does not need to know** about controller".

Comment: aside from you mishearing what the author said, you also misunderstand how the view (HTML) works.  the HTML is composed by the angular process, and all expressions, models, etc. are processed by angular, not the view.  the view doesn't really even know that it's been changed, much less the presence of any other entity, such as a controller, or indeed angular at all.  The view is nothing more than a template.

Comment: for example, it's not necessary for you to annotate your HTML items with `onChange()` events to update the controller, where your view is actively notifying some controller of an event.